# Create table and insert into one command not working

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, sqlite

I have this C# code to execute SqLite command:

```
 using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(localPath, true))
            {
                SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(conn);
                command.CommandText = query;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

When I run this SQL with C# code , I've got empty table:

```
 CREATE TABLE [MyEmailList] (
      [MyEmailListId]  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT 
    ,[FirstName]  TEXT 
    ,[LastName]  TEXT 
    ,[Email]  TEXT 
    ,[Link]  TEXT 
    );


     INSERT INTO [MyEmailList] ( [FirstName],[LastName],[Email],[Link]) VALUES 
('SomeFirstName2','SomeLastname2','SomeEmail2@host.com','http://mywebsite.com/link2.htm')
    ,('SomeFirstName3','SomeLastname3','SomeEmail3@host.com','http://mywebsite.com/link3.htm')
    ,('SomeFirstName4','SomeLastname4','SomeEmail4@host.com','http://mywebsite.com/link4.htm')
    ,('SomeFirstName5','SomeLastname5','SomeEmail5@host.com','http://mywebsite.com/link5.htm');
```

So it looks like table has been created but insert part of script wasn't running.
When I run create table and insert into separated commands it works.

Is there way to run create table and insert into one command  ?

UPD:I've tried the same with connection and including GO into SQL statements,still doesn't work.

```
    using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(localPath, true))
            {

                var q1 = @" CREATE TABLE [MyEmailList] (
      [MyEmailListId]  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT 
    ,[FirstName]  TEXT 
    ,[LastName]  TEXT 
    ,[Email]  TEXT 
    ,[Link]  TEXT 
    );
    GO;

     INSERT INTO [MyEmailList] ( [FirstName],[LastName],[Email],[Link]) VALUES 
('SomeFirstName2','SomeLastname2','SomeEmail2@host.com','http://mywebsite.com/link2.htm')
    ,('SomeFirstName3','SomeLastname3','SomeEmail3@host.com','http://mywebsite.com/link3.htm')
    ,('SomeFirstName4','SomeLastname4','SomeEmail4@host.com','http://mywebsite.com/link4.htm')
    ,('SomeFirstName5','SomeLastname5','SomeEmail5@host.com','http://mywebsite.com/link5.htm');
GO;
";

                conn.Execute(q1);
                conn.Commit();
                conn.Close();

            }
```

Comment: if you put  GO between commands , it doesn't work ?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. A simple test inserted the row as expected so clearly something else is wrong.

Comment: How you get it working ? I've added another example.

Answer (score 0):

You can call  `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` after creating a table, and then again after insert.

```
  command.CommandText = " CREATE TABLE [MyEmailList] (
      [MyEmailListId]  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT 
    ,[FirstName]  TEXT 
    ,[LastName]  TEXT 
    ,[Email]  TEXT 
    ,[Link]  TEXT 
    );";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    command.CommandText = " INSERT INTO [MyEmailList] ( [FirstName],[LastName],[Email],[Link]) VALUES 
('SomeFirstName2','SomeLastname2','SomeEmail2@host.com','http://mywebsite.com/link2.htm')
    ,('SomeFirstName3','SomeLastname3','SomeEmail3@host.com','http://mywebsite.com/link3.htm')
    ,('SomeFirstName4','SomeLastname4','SomeEmail4@host.com','http://mywebsite.com/link4.htm')
    ,('SomeFirstName5','SomeLastname5','SomeEmail5@host.com','http://mywebsite.com/link5.htm');";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also you can add a check to see if the table already exists.

```
 var myEmailList = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
 if (name != null && name.ToString() == "MyEmailList")
        return;
```

Comment: Actually putting the two SQL's into one string will work, just tested it.

Comment: Yup, however my questions is : is that possible to run create table and insert into one sql and one command ? my sqlite manager runs them both in one sql with no problem.